# Browserify external doesn't work

Tags: browserify

I'm trying to split a bundle on two parts. For example to move one package with all it's dependencies to separate bundle file.

To exclude package from main bundle I declare it as external:

```
browserify({
  entries: ['./src/index.js'],
  extensions: ['.js'],
  debug: true
})
.external(['PdfKit']) // Specify all vendors as external source
.bundle()
.pipe(source('app.js'))
.pipe(buffer())
.pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
```

The problem is that app.js contans full code of PdfKit package with all dependencies.

Full working demo awailable here: https://github.com/motz-art/browserify-external-test

How can I remove some (but not all) packages with all it's dependencies from app.js?

Answer (score 0):

The `external` method is case sensetive. And must match package name as it appears inside `require`.

In my case `'PdfKit'` is marked as external but index.js references `'pdfKit'` so filter returns `true`, but than the package it self is resolved because windows is case insensetive.